# Verifying user authorization from inside the application with Spring Security Filter Chain programmatically

Tags: spring-security, spring-hateoas

I'm currently developing an application with Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE and Spring Security 4.1.3.RELEASE. The application has Rest Controllers and receives and responds json messages. This application will be communicating with an Angular application.
I already have authentication and authorization working with configurations like:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/foo/bar/**")
        .access("(hasRole('OPERATOR') && hasRole('MAKER')) || hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

And rules in the RestControllers methods like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(#id) || hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

All that is working without problems, now I'm adding Spring Hateoas. 
I know that Hateoas is not related to user authorization to resources, but I want to be able to send to the angular app additional information. Not just the link of the resource but what actions (http verbs) the user has access to.

I don't want to do this to improve the security of the application, it's just to improve the user experience. In the Angular app I want to be able to activate or deactivate a functionality depending of what the server is sending.

So here comes my question, is there any available class in Spring Security that I can Autowire in order to test a URL and see if the user is authorized to execute a specific action to that particular URL?

All the classes mentioned in the Spring Security documentation that I have tested so far are not recognized by the @Autowire annotation.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, bud aren't you looking for `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` ?

Comment: @user1315357 I'm aware of that method, with that I get the user profile. But in order to know if the user can execute for example POST http://example.com/foo/bar I will need to codify a logic that is not using the rules that I declared in the antMatcher as described in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, look at [WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.html) it might suits your needs.

```
isAllowed(String contextPath, String uri, String method, Authentication authentication)
```

You can see it in action for example [here](https://github.com/skprasadu/spring-security-examples/blob/master/spring-security-methodlevel-security/src/main/java/com/example/springsecurity/web/controllers/WelcomeController.java).

Comment: For some reason the WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator is not using the rules declared with @PreAuthorize. Maybe is a bug, I'm not sure. I'm going to create a sample project to recreate the problem and if I think is a bug I'm going to post it on GitHub.

Comment: Share your prototype please.

Comment: I opened an issue in github: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4159). In the description of the issue you can find the link to a sample project demonstrating the problem.